# Is it possible and worth to optimize the following code using yield If so, how

Tags: c#

As the title says, is it possible to optimize the following code by using yield, is it worth and if so, how?

```
public static void LoadSettings(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(fileName);
        var userNodes = xml.SelectNodes("/settings");

        foreach (XmlNode node in userNodes)
        {
            globals.username = node.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText;
            globals.password = node.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;
            globals.rank = node.SelectSingleNode("rank").InnerText;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oops, something is wrong.");
    }
}
```

**Edit: Thanks for answers guys!**

Comment: no -> test yield first in a test project to see what it does because I don't think you understand

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Can you give an example of what you have in mind how `yield` should be used here? You don't even return anything.....

Comment: You can`t and the code is ok, doesn`t need an optimization

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. `yield return` can only implemented for methods actually returning something. You don't have a return value, so the answer is no.

As an example, this could be an application of `yield return`, but that would change the meaning of your method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Setting> LoadSettings(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(fileName);
        var userNodes = xml.SelectNodes("/settings");

        foreach (XmlNode node in userNodes)
        {
            Setting globals = new Setting();
            globals.username = node.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText;
            globals.password = node.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;
            globals.rank = node.SelectSingleNode("rank").InnerText;

            yield return globals;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oops, something is wrong.");
    }
}
```